# Prevent foreign key property from being reset in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my EF code first model, I have two entities:

```
class User 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Friend")]
    public virtual ICollection<Invitation> Invitations { get; set; }
}

class Invitation
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public int FriendId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("FriendId")]
     public User Friend { get; set; }
}
```

So the FriendId property is the foreign key into the User entity. Now when I add a new Invitation object to the User.Invitations collection, the Invitation.Friend property is populated accordingly, which is what I want.

However, when I **remove** an Invitation object from the User.Invitations collection, I want the Friend property of the removed Invitation object to retain its value. Currently, EF will set it to null. How do I prevent that? I'm using EF 6.0.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you removing an invitation from the User if you don't want to break the relationship between the two?

Comment: I want the remove the invitation when the user wants to delete it, but I want to keep the Invitation object for book keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code first model will generate the following schema:

```
Users
-----
Id : int PK

Invitations
-----------
Id : int PK
FriendId : int FK NOT NULL
```

The relationship between an Invitation and a User is modelled at the database level using the FriendId on the Invitations table. As you have made FriendId not nullable, this is a required relationship. I.e. an Invitation in the database cannot exist without being associated to a User.

Within your entity model, when an Invitation is removed from a User, the corresponding Invitation will be deleted from the Invitations table. Logically this is the only cause of action due to the way the relationship has been setup.

To keep the invitation in the Invitations table (as an orphaned entity), simply mark the referencing foreign key property as nullable.

```
class Invitation
{
   public int? FriendId { get; set; }
}
```

The call to `.Remove` on the User entity will then mark the **relationship** as deleted without deleting the actual child entity.

You mention you want to keep the Invitation to User association for auditing purposes. In which case, perhaps an InvitationAudit able would be your best option?

Comment: Is there a way to tell EF that when I remove an Invitation from a User, don't delete it from the Invitations table?